# Scrampling code,Neighbour list in edge mode android

Tags: android, android-layout

> I get neighbourt list in 3G mode.but i couldn't able to get in 2G
>   mode.
>       can any one help me to get out the neighbouring list in 2g mode?
>       Scrampling code i couldn't able to get in 2G mode...how can i get this value

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
textGsmCellLocation.setText(cellLocation.toString());
textCID.setText("gsm cell id: " + String.valueOf(cid));
textLAC.setText("gsm location area code: " + String.valueOf(lac));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android.telephony.TelephonyManager` and `getNeighboringCellInfo()`

Watch out because it doesn't work well in all the device according with their hardware implementation.